# Add-AzureKeyVaultKey fails with Operation "import" is not allowed

Tags: azure-keyvault

I was able to create Azure key value successfully but I am unable import the PFX file successfully. Here is the command I used:

```
$securepfxpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString –String '123' –AsPlainText –Force
$key1 = Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName 'MyKeyVault' -Name 'MyKey' -KeyFilePath 'C:\mycert.io.pfx' -KeyFilePassword $securepfxpwd
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Add-AzureKeyVaultKey : **Operation "import" is not allowed**
At line:1 char:9
+ $key1 = Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName 'MyKeyVault' -Name 'MyKey ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureKeyVaultKey], KeyVaultClientException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.AddAzureKeyVaultKey*
```

When I used command: `Get-AzureRmKeyVault`, I got following information for access keys:

```
*SKU                             : Standard
Enabled For Deployment?          : False
Enabled For Template Deployment? : False
Enabled For Disk Encryption?     : False
**Access Policies                :** 
Tags                             :*
```

Here are my questions:

1. Should I be giving myself permissions to import using Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy?
2. If so, what would be the parameters for this command to give myself permissions to import the cert?

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue today.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -UserPrincipalName $upn -PermissionsToCertificates all
```

Valid values are `get, list, delete, create, import, update, managecontacts, getissuers, listissuers, setissuers, deleteissuers, all`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.keyvault/v2.5.0/set-azurermkeyvaultaccesspolicy